# How does one explicitly compute the rate function for a given probability distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, large-deviation-theory

For a given probability distribution $\mu$, the associated rate function is $I_\mu(x) = sup \left \lbrace x \lambda - ln \left( \int e^{\lambda t} \mu (dx) \right) \right \rbrace$, and if there happens to be a probability distribution function $f(x)$ for $\mu$ this becomes  $I_\mu(x) = sup \left \lbrace x \lambda - ln \left( \int f(x) e^{\lambda t} dx \right) \right \rbrace$. That's all well and good, but how does one actually *calculate* what this function is for a particular distribution?

For example, if $\mu$ has the normal distribution $N(m, \sigma^2)$, then its distribution function is $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(x-m)^2/(2\sigma^2)}$ (at least according to wikipedia it is, anyhow). Is there some known way to then explicitly calculate what $I_\mu(x)$ is as a basic function of x, that is, to render it in terms of something that doesn't involve a supremum over all real numbers? When I tried just taking the definition, putting the distribution function in, and chugging along, I got something that requires a calculation of $\int e^{((2\sigma^2 \lambda + 2m)t - t^2)/(2\sigma^2)} dt$, and even fudging this integral's value using wolfram alpha (which is obviously not a satisfactory way to solve the problem) I wound up with something that I don't really know how to take a general supremum of.

Comment: For the normal distribution the rate function can be calculated explicitly, but in general this is rather complicated. Normal distribution: Use that the exponential moments of the normal distribution are known.

Comment: Is knowing the exponential moments of a particular distribution all that is needed for the method you're suggesting, or does the normal distribution have other "nice" properties that make it work only in this case?

Comment: Well, they are known and they have a very nice form. For a function $F$, the function $F^{\ast}$ defined by $$F^{\ast}(x) := \sup_{\lambda} (\lambda x - F(\lambda))$$ is called Legendre transform. Here, $F$ corresponds to the logarithmic moment generating function. Even if $F$ is given (i.e. the exponential moments can be calculated explicitly), it is in general hard to calculate $F^{\ast}(x)$.

Comment: What @saz explained. For the normal distribution, a first reduction is that $I_\mu(x)=J((x-m)/\sigma)$ where $J$ is the functional for the standard normal distribution (of a random variable $Z$, say). Then the easy identity $E(e^{\lambda Z})=e^{\lambda^2/2}$ yields $J(x)=x^2/2$, hence $I_\mu(x)=(x-m)^2/(2\sigma^2)$.